# PyTorch: redundancy between map_location and .to(device)?

Tags: pytorch, checkpointing

The [PyTorch documentation on torch.save and torch.load](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-on-cpu-load-on-gpu) contains the following section:

### Save on CPU, Load on GPU

Save:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

Load:

```
device = torch.device("cuda")
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location="cuda:0"))  # Choose whatever GPU device number you want
model.to(device)
```

> When loading a model on a GPU that was trained and saved on CPU, set
> the map_location argument in the torch.load() function to
> cuda:device_id. This loads the model to a given GPU device. Next, be
> sure to call model.to(torch.device('cuda')) to convert the model’s
> parameter tensors to CUDA tensors.

Isn't calling `.to(device)` in this example redundant since calling `load` with `map_location` must have already placed it in the GPU?

Moreover, the text says "Next, be sure to call model.to(torch.device('cuda')) to convert the model’s parameter tensors to CUDA tensors". But wasn't that conversion already done during `load` with `map_location`?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`torch.load`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html) with `map_location` set to a cuda device will load the state to the desired device. However, it is likely that when [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) is called, the tensors are copied to the model's CPU, including if the model is on the CPU. If you test your code without the `model.to(device)`, you will notice your model is, in fact, not on the GPU. The state was on the GPU, but the model never was. You can read more [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-load-does-not-map-to-gpu-as-advertised/74637/4).

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=device))
```

This means you are required to use the `model.to(device)`.

You can prevent that by first transferring the model to the Cuda device, and then loading your state. But overall the number of transfers to the GPU is the same, 2: 1st with your initialized model, then 2nd the state.

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=device))
```

You should be able to reduce the number of transfers by first loading the state on the CPU, then transfer the model to the GPU:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location='cpu'))
model.to(device)
```

Comment: Thanks. My (incorrect) mental model was that we were doing `model = torch.load(PATH, map_location='cuda:0')`, but of course we were just loading the state dict. I imagine that doing `model = torch.load(PATH, map_location='cuda:0')` would indeed make `model.to(device)` unnecessary, but I understand that that is not recommended in order to keep flexibility, as explained in https://forums.fast.ai/t/why-is-state-dict-the-recommended-method-for-saving-pytorch-models/81709/2

Comment: I am now rethinking this a bit and a new question came up. Your final suggestion is to use `map_location='cpu'` to avoid copies. But the documentation, shown in the question, suggests using `map_location='cuda:0'`. Given your explanation, that is not necessary. Is the documentation incorrect (or at least wasteful) then?

Comment: In the documentation page of [`torch.load`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html#:~:text=You%20can%20call%20torch.load(..%2C%20map_location%3D%27cpu%27)%20and%20then%20load_state_dict()%20to%20avoid%20GPU%20RAM%20surge%20when%20loading%20a%20model%20checkpoint.), it is stated in a note: *"You can call `torch.load(.., map_location='cpu')` and then `load_state_dict()` to avoid GPU RAM surge when loading a model checkpoint."* So in case transferring from CPU to CUDA is a bottleneck, I would recommend first loading on the CPU.